# Why boost::aio is asynchronous when its implementation is based on epoll(synchronous)

Tags: linux, model, kernel, aio

We know:

(1) epoll is synchronous, based on user query/system notify. A while loop is used to call all woke up fds.

(2) boost::asio declares itself to be "asynchronous", but its implementation on linux is using epoll.

My question is: how can you implement "asyn" using a "syn" system call? Unless you use some kernel/system supported aio interface, right?

Please help to correct my confusions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"synchronous" normally refers to an operation that does not return control back to the caller until it has completed.

`epoll` is synchronous in the sense that its operation (returning fds with pending completions/actions) is complete by the time it returns.

Reading from or writing to a socket however is still asynchronous in the sense that the operation to read or write is still not complete when the function call returns. The actual I/O work may be done asynchronously, and `epoll` will tell you when it's done. The work will be performed regardless of if and when you call `epoll`, `epoll` is just the mechanism to signal completions back to you, not the function that performs the work.

Comment: "The actual I/O work is done asynchronously" => "The actual I/O work *may* be done asynchronously" and you're good :)